# How to make app content searchable for android TV

Tags: android, search, android-tv

So I followed the android tv documentation and downloaded the sample apps from here:

```
https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback
```

I got it running on an actual nexus device and most of the app works fine. The portion I'm most interested in though isn't working for me.

When I try searching for something using the google search in the home screen I get no search results from the leanback sample app at all and I see the following errors in the logcat comming from the sample app.

```
1822-1838/com.example.android.leanback E/JavaBinder﹕ *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getType(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:130)
        at com.example.android.leanback.PaginatedCursor.<init>(PaginatedCursor.java:65)
        at com.example.android.leanback.VideoDatabase.query(VideoDatabase.java:170)
        at com.example.android.leanback.VideoDatabase.getWordMatch(VideoDatabase.java:150)
        at com.example.android.leanback.VideoContentProvider.getSuggestions(VideoContentProvider.java:112)
        at com.example.android.leanback.VideoContentProvider.query(VideoContentProvider.java:85)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:950)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:210)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

I followed this example in my own app and I get similar errors plus others as Im sure I havent wired everything up the right way. If anyone has gotten in app content searchable I would appreciate some input on getting it working correctly.

**EDIT:**

After doing some debugging I can see that the cursor that gets put into the paginatedCursor always is empty. Its probably something with the way the queries are formatted. Im playing with the query building now and if I get it working Ill post back.

Comment: So I got this working by removing the * in the query building portion and then I also created my own db to pull results from. Then it finally worked.

Comment: If you get the lastest version ? In my case, i have 1 result if i search Gmail

Answer (score -3):

Android TV Search uses the standard Android search mechanism to search third party apps. You can find API guides about the Android search mechanism [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html).

You can also look at legacy sample app called “Searchable Dictionary” demonstrating the search mechanism. It  can be found in Android SDK sample apps. A lot of column names prefixed with “SUGGEST_COLUMN_” are defined in the SearchManager class  representing what data fields your app could provide, such as [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1).

In Android Lollipop release, some new columns are introduced which  are designed for Android TV search. You can find the newly added columns [here.](http://developer.android.com/preview/reference.html)

Some important column are:

SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1
SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2
SUGGEST_COLUMN_RESULT_CARD_IMAGE
SUGGEST_COLUMN_CONTENT_TYPE
SUGGEST_COLUMN_VIDEO_WIDTH
SUGGEST_COLUMN_VIDEO_HEIGHT
SUGGEST_COLUMN_PRODUCTION_YEAR
SUGGEST_COLUMN_DURATION

Comment: Hi Verma thanks for answering. Ive read the documentation through a few times and I get the theory behind how everything is supposed to work but in practice something is not working correctly. Even googles own sample app doesnt work and gives errors. If you have some feed back on how to correct the issue I posted above I would love to hear it.